# Navigation tab hovering

Tags: css, hover

I need help creating something like this link (http://www.standardchartered.co.in/borrow/)

When the user hovers over the navigation, the grey triangle image will appear. I'm not very sure how to go about doing it. Please help!

Comment: There are more than 5 navigation menus on that page. Which one are you reffering to?

Comment: Well as he said, the one where the grey triangle appears.

Comment: Hi, all the navigation tabs have the triangle image :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use a plug-in, possibly for jQuery. There are many drop down menu plugins available. A google search for "jquery drop down menu" will help you. One of the first results for me is:
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/

The second one down on that page appears to have the effect you want, but it also depends on how you want the rest of the menu to appear. You will need to do some research and choose one that suits you.

OR, if you just want a grey triangle to appear, without the menu, when you hover over an element, then some css like this is what you want:

```
li:hover {
    background:url('./images/grey_triangle.png') center bottom;
}
```

Which says, when the li element is hovered, use ./images/grey_triangle.png as the background image and place it in the center at the bottom of the element. You would need to create your own grey triangle, set appropriate padding etc, but that is the basic css you need for the effect.

Comment: Hi Nigel, 

i did the exact same way, but i noticed the triangle image will disappear after my mouse moves to the dropdown div.

Comment: You would need to have the drop down menu be a child of the li for my example to work. Like this: <li>Menu Item<ul><li>child menu...</li></ul></li>